# How to mute Microphone when recording from headset

Tags: android, bluetooth, media-player, audio-recording

I am making a application to record audio from bluetooth headset. After that, the signal sound from headset will be played in to speaker of android phone. However, my problem is that some signal from microphone of android phone is also played. I want to mute microphone of android during playing. Is it possible. I am refering some link but it does not useful. Please give me one solution to turn of my microphone. This is my setting

```
_audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    int maxJitter = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(SAMPLE_RATE, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

    track = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION, SAMPLE_RATE, AudioFormat.CHANNEL`enter code here`_OUT_MONO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, maxJitter, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
    _audioManager.startBluetoothSco();
    _audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM); 

    _audioManager.setMicrophoneMute( false);
    _audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
    setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
```

This is my expected work
[image]
You can download the source code at [Audio record and speak via headset bluetooth](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0wjll7q01ahg402/AudioDemo51.rar?dl=0)

Comment: `_audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM); ` <-- that's wrong. `setMode` expects an audio _mode_, not an audio _stream type_. Also, `setVolumeControlStream` expects a stream type, not an audio mode.

Comment: Thank Michael. So based on your suggestion, I delete two line setMode and setVolumeControlStream. However, I did not hear any sound from my android speaker. What is happen?This is my project https://www.dropbox.com/s/0wjll7q01ahg402/AudioDemo51.rar?dl=0

Comment: @Michael: Let see my expected work