# Connecting With A Paired Bluetooth Device

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I used the following code to get a list of all the paired devices in the mobile phone:

```
  BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
  Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

  List<String> s = new ArrayList<String>();
  for (BluetoothDevice bt : pairedDevices) {
      s.add(bt.getName());
  }

  for (int index = 0; index < s.size(); index++) {
      Toast.makeText(this, "Device Name: " + s.get(index), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
```

I have Bluetooth headsets that **are already paired** and I want my application to connect to those headphones in this way:

[image: In this way]

Comment: What is your question? Is it not working? what exact error are you running into?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically connect to paired Bluetooth device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171248/programmatically-connect-to-paired-bluetooth-device)