# making the app searching for Bluetooth mac address and connect to it if available "Android Studio"

Tags: java, android-studio, bluetooth, arduino, mac-address

I'm not android studio developer or java developer but regarding for my graduation project I need to make an android app that connects to HC-05 Bluetooth module "Arduino", then starts to transmit and receive bytes ... I have found a lot of projects that connects to the Bluetooth module by showing you a list of Bluetooth devices then you can choose which one you want to connect ...
but I don't want to use this method I want to find a method that searches for a specific Bluetooth mac address and if it available, start connecting to it, if it not available, the app will continue searching ...

I don't have any experience how can programmatically make this.
so please be patient :D

*I have done the XML design...*

**I want to add the mac address connecting code here**

```
package mdluex.smartx;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class ActivityControlCenter extends AppCompatActivity {

    private int room1_str = 1;
    private int room2_str = 0;
    private int room3_str = 1;
    private int room4_str = 1;
    private int room5_str = 1;
    private int room6_str = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_control_center);

        final RelativeLayout room1_btn = (RelativeLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.room1_btn);
        final TextView room1_st = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.room1_st);
        final ImageView room1_img = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.room1_img);
        room1_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (room1_str == 0){
                    room1_str = 1;
                    room1_btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_grid_nor);
                    room1_st.setText("ON");
                    room1_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.lamp_on);
                }
                else {
                    room1_str = 0;
                    room1_btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_grid_off);
                    room1_st.setText("OFF");
                    room1_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.lamp_off);
                }
            }
        });

        final RelativeLayout room2_btn = (RelativeLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.room2_btn);
        final TextView room2_st = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.room2_st);
        final ImageView room2_img = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.room2_img);
        room2_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (room2_str == 0){
                    room2_str = 1;
                    room2_btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_grid_nor);
                    room2_st.setText("ON");
                    room2_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.lamp_on);
                }
                else {
                    room2_str = 0;
                    room2_btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_grid_off);
                    room2_st.setText("OFF");
                    room2_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.lamp_off);
                }
            }
        });

        final RelativeLayout room3_btn = (RelativeLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.room3_btn);
        final TextView room3_st = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.room3_st);
        final ImageView room3_img = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.room3_img);
        room3_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (room3_str == 0){
                    room3_str = 1;
                    room3_btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_grid_nor);
                    room3_st.setText("ON");
                    room3_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.lamp_on);
                }
                else {
                    room3_str = 0;
                    room3_btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_grid_off);
                    room3_st.setText("OFF");
                    room3_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.lamp_off);
                }
            }
        });

        final RelativeLayout room4_btn = (RelativeLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.room4_btn);
        final TextView room4_st = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.room4_st);
        final ImageView room4_img = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.room4_img);
        room4_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (room4_str == 0){
                    room4_str = 1;
                    room4_btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_grid_nor);
                    room4_st.setText("ON");
                    room4_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.lamp_on);
                }
                else {
                    room4_str = 0;
                    room4_btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_grid_off);
                    room4_st.setText("OFF");
                    room4_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.lamp_off);
                }
            }
        });

        final RelativeLayout room5_btn = (RelativeLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.room5_btn);
        final TextView room5_st = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.room5_st);
        final ImageView room5_img = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.room5_img);
        room5_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (room5_str == 0){
                    room5_str = 1;
                    room5_btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_grid_nor);
                    room5_st.setText("ON");
                    room5_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.lamp_on);
                }
                else {
                    room5_str = 0;
                    room5_btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_grid_off);
                    room5_st.setText("OFF");
                    room5_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.lamp_off);
                }
            }
        });

        final RelativeLayout room6_btn = (RelativeLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.room6_btn);
        final TextView room6_st = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.room6_st);
        final ImageView room6_img = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.room6_img);
        room6_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (room6_str == 0){
                    room6_str = 1;
                    room6_btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_grid_nor);
                    room6_st.setText("ON");
                    room6_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.lamp_on);
                }
                else {
                    room6_str = 0;
                    room6_btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_grid_off);
                    room6_st.setText("OFF");
                    room6_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.lamp_off);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**this is the XML design**
[Activity Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eyi8h.png)

**[the full project code on GitHub](https://github.com/mdluex/SmartX-Android-App.git)**

Comment: What have you tried? There are plenty of examples that scan all the devices, then filter for a wanted MAC address, or also connect to non-discoverable device by MAC. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16902500/connect-to-device-with-bluetooth-address-on-string, also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922893/connect-to-non-discoverable-bluetooth-device).

Comment: thanks, Maximilian :D but like what I said I'm not a developer ... where can I add this code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found the solution :D** 
thanks, guys ...

[My full project](https://github.com/mdluex/SmartX-Android-App.git) contains this code:

```
package mdluex.smartx;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;


public class ActivityControlCenter extends AppCompatActivity {

    private int room1_str = 1;
    private int room2_str = 0;
    private int room3_str = 1;
    private int room4_str = 1;
    private int room5_str = 1;
    private int room6_str = 1;
    String deviceName = "HC-05";
    BluetoothDevice result = null;
    BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter=BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    private BluetoothSocket socket;
    private OutputStream outputStream;
    private InputStream inputStream;
    private final UUID PORT_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");//Serial Port Service ID


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_control_center);

        if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Device doesnt Support Bluetooth",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if(!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled())
        {
            Intent enableAdapter = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableAdapter, 0);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        Set<BluetoothDevice> devices = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        if (devices != null) {
            for (BluetoothDevice device : devices) {
                if (deviceName.equals(device.getName())) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"SamrtX is available ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    result = device;
                    boolean connected=true;
                    try {
                        socket = result.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(PORT_UUID);
                        socket.connect();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Connected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        connected=false;
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"SamrtX is not available ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    if(connected)
                    {
                        try {
                            outputStream=socket.getOutputStream();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        try {
                            inputStream=socket.getInputStream();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        final RelativeLayout room1_btn = (RelativeLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.room1_btn);
        final TextView room1_st = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.room1_st);
        final ImageView room1_img = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.room1_img);
        room1_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (room1_str == 0){
                    room1_str = 1;
                    if (socket!=null)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            socket.getOutputStream().write("a".toString().getBytes());
                        }
                        catch (IOException e)
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                    room1_btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_grid_nor);
                    room1_st.setText("ON");
                    room1_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.lamp_on);
                }
                else {
                    room1_str = 0;
                    if (socket!=null)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            socket.getOutputStream().write("b".toString().getBytes());
                        }
                        catch (IOException e)
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                    room1_btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_grid_off);
                    room1_st.setText("OFF");
                    room1_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.lamp_off);
                }
            }
        });

        final RelativeLayout room2_btn = (RelativeLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.room2_btn);
        final TextView room2_st = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.room2_st);
        final ImageView room2_img = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.room2_img);
        room2_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (room2_str == 0){
                    room2_str = 1;
                    room2_btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_grid_nor);
                    room2_st.setText("ON");
                    room2_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.lamp_on);
                }
                else {
                    room2_str = 0;
                    room2_btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_grid_off);
                    room2_st.setText("OFF");
                    room2_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.lamp_off);
                }
            }
        });

        final RelativeLayout room3_btn = (RelativeLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.room3_btn);
        final TextView room3_st = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.room3_st);
        final ImageView room3_img = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.room3_img);
        room3_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (room3_str == 0){
                    room3_str = 1;
                    room3_btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_grid_nor);
                    room3_st.setText("ON");
                    room3_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.lamp_on);
                }
                else {
                    room3_str = 0;
                    room3_btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_grid_off);
                    room3_st.setText("OFF");
                    room3_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.lamp_off);
                }
            }
        });

        final RelativeLayout room4_btn = (RelativeLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.room4_btn);
        final TextView room4_st = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.room4_st);
        final ImageView room4_img = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.room4_img);
        room4_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (room4_str == 0){
                    room4_str = 1;
                    room4_btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_grid_nor);
                    room4_st.setText("ON");
                    room4_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.lamp_on);
                }
                else {
                    room4_str = 0;
                    room4_btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_grid_off);
                    room4_st.setText("OFF");
                    room4_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.lamp_off);
                }
            }
        });

        final RelativeLayout room5_btn = (RelativeLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.room5_btn);
        final TextView room5_st = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.room5_st);
        final ImageView room5_img = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.room5_img);
        room5_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (room5_str == 0){
                    room5_str = 1;
                    room5_btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_grid_nor);
                    room5_st.setText("ON");
                    room5_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.lamp_on);
                }
                else {
                    room5_str = 0;
                    room5_btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_grid_off);
                    room5_st.setText("OFF");
                    room5_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.lamp_off);
                }
            }
        });

        final RelativeLayout room6_btn = (RelativeLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.room6_btn);
        final TextView room6_st = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.room6_st);
        final ImageView room6_img = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.room6_img);
        room6_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (room6_str == 0){
                    room6_str = 1;
                    room6_btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_grid_nor);
                    room6_st.setText("ON");
                    room6_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.lamp_on);
                }
                else {
                    room6_str = 0;
                    room6_btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_grid_off);
                    room6_st.setText("OFF");
                    room6_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.lamp_off);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: When you have a link to your own things, please make sure it's blatantly obvious that it's yours -- see my edit (which should be coming in a few secnods).